# Upgrade to 16.10: PAM-CGFS errors

Tags: 16.04, lxc, pam, cgroup

Since upgrading my Ubuntu host server installation from 15.10 to 16.04.1 yesterday these errors fill my log:

`PAM-CGFS[28483]: Failed to create a cgroup for user root`

Googling this turns up nothing useful.
What could cause this and how can I get rid of them?

**EDIT**: I put the latest output of `journalctl --boot 0` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/22553947/ . It doesn't contain the error yet, as I just rebooted. I'm hoping the boot messages may help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't trigger directly on boot ,  but happens after invoking some command which uses cgroups and tries accessing non-existent cgroup . In my case , it was lxc-ls  .

See https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2016-August/012172.html

Anyhow,try modifying /etc/pam.d/common-session{,-noninteractive} , adding cpuacct to

> session optional        pam_cgfs.so -c freezer,memory,name=systemd

fixed it for me .

Comment: Hi frater_sourcecode, Welcome to askubuntu! Please add some more information why your solution solves the problem. From your link someone can see that there exists now a patch! Further for your solution  `sudo apt install lxc` package has to be installed. The pam configs are very criticlal in terms of security.  Explain what and why you change to lxc . What does `cpuacct` mean?